# Launching Elastic Kibana - internal server 500 error - [illegal_argument_exception] application privileges must refer to at least one resource"}

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-cloud

I launched Kibana in my Elastic Cloud account and see this message. Why can I not log in to my Kibana account? I restarted my deployment and see the same error.

[image]

If this is relevant, I should add that there is an issue with my Elastic Search. It is apparently "unhealthy".
[image]

However, when I launch the Elastic Search instance, I get an apparently healthy response.

```
{
  "name" : "instance-0000000003",
  "cluster_name" : "d972<hidden for privacy>665aee2",
  "cluster_uuid" : "9IOP<hidden for privacy>iflw",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "7.5.2",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "tar",
    "build_hash" : "8bec5<hidden for privacy>580cd1afcdf",
    "build_date" : "2020-01-15T12:11:52.313576Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "8.3.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Comment: I am also experiencing this issue.

Comment: I deleted my deployment and created a new one. Works fine. Not ideal if you already have a lot of data in your current deployment.

Comment: Force Restart of my Kibana instance also works for me, but I need to do it frequently. I think something is deleting a .kibana* index, related to this issue https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/26845

Answer (score 1):

If you stop the Kibana server and restart it, the default space document will be created.

Answer (score 0):

You get this error if .kibana index gets deleted while Kibana is running. It seems something is removing your .kibana index, in my case it was Curator. Thus, I added these two lines in Curator's action_file.yml file under actions/1/filters:

```
---
actions:
  1:
    filters:
    - filtertype: kibana
      exclude: True
```